# Nlog.Targets.Syslog memory leak issue

Tags: c#, nlog, syslog

Im using NLog.Targets.Syslog to log messages to  Kiwi Syslog. recently i found that this target type is consuming lot of memory.

[image]

Nlog.config code

```
<target xsi:type="sl:Syslog" name="syslogForImporter">

    <sl:layout xsi:type="SimpleLayout" text=" NewSVC: ${date:format=yyyy-MM-ddTHH\:mm\s.fff} ${message}${exception:format=ToString,StackTrace}" />

    <sl:enforcement>
    <sl:splitOnNewLine>true</sl:splitOnNewLine>
    <sl:transliterate>true</sl:transliterate>
    <sl:replaceInvalidCharacters>true</sl:replaceInvalidCharacters>
    <sl:truncateFieldsToMaxLength>true</sl:truncateFieldsToMaxLength>
    <sl:truncateMessageTo>1024</sl:truncateMessageTo>
  </sl:enforcement>
  <sl:messageCreation>
    <!--Facility as log audit-->
    <sl:facility>Audit</sl:facility>
    <sl:rfc>Rfc3164</sl:rfc>
    <sl:rfc3164 hostname="${machinename}" tag="${logger}"  />
  </sl:messageCreation>
  <sl:messageSend>
    <sl:protocol>UDP</sl:protocol>
    <sl:udp>
      <sl:server>10.20.30.40</sl:server>
      <sl:port>514</sl:port>
    </sl:udp>

  </sl:messageSend>
</target>
```

After disabling the target rule for syslog, the memory utilization decreased drastically.

Can someone help me out with this issues. Im using c#, NLog V4.4.12,NLog.Targets.Syslog V4.0.0.0

Comment: I think this is better as bug-report (and see it's already here: https://github.com/graffen/NLog.Targets.Syslog/issues/101)

Comment: @Julian i have raised that bug